# Boot important files

Tags: boot, filesystem, data-recovery, 19.10, boot-repair

this packages what i [deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V28eU.jpg)  
Then my pc cannot boot ubuntu and give me this [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCbMV.jpg)  so i tried to install this package again but my PC cannot fetch some file i think this because cannot connect to internet

Comment: You deleted a lot of necessary packages. What did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you seem to have destroyed your system quite effectively.

1) Make a new Ubuntu install LiveUSB.

2) Boot into the "Try Ubuntu" environment.

You have two choices for step 3):

- Backup your data and reinstall (easiest)
- Chroot into the broken system and reinstall the `libreadline8` package (fastest...if you know how, but slowest if you don't know how)

**Advice**: If you use wildcards in apt, *read your output carefully*. That's the only warning you will get.